# Run sudo command using Java processBuilder

Tags: java, java-8, iptables, processbuilder

I need to run a sudo command from within java, and redirect the output to a file, using processbuilder or similar.

Two questions:

1. Will piping the sudo password using echo work as follows?
2. Although the file gets created, nothing is ever written to it. Any ideas why?

   ```
   ProcessBuilder conntrack_process = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "-c", "echo '<passwordhere>' | sudo conntrack -L");
   conntrack_process.redirectOutput(new java.io.File("/home/<homedir>/conntrack_out.txt"));
   Process ct_process = conntrack_process.start();
   ct_process.waitFor();
   ct_process.destroy();
   ```

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Can your task be solved by running your java from some .sh file with setuid bit and making root as file owner? Just asking cause you won't need to bother with sudo then

Comment: Thanks, I would like to accept Roman's answer, but there's no check mark as per docs: "click on the check mark beside the answer". Any ideas why?

Comment: That's because it was a comment, not an answer. Now I added an answer.

Comment: While piping via `echo` might work, it’s strongly discouraged as other processes can see the commandline, hence the password, while the process is running. Since the Java `Process` API already provides you with a pipe, there is no need to create another one. Just run `sudo` as sub-process and use `process.getInput().write(/*password as bytes plus \n */)`…

Comment: @the.Legend - Setuid root scripts are VERY dangerous.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/2910/1269

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to use `-S` with `sudo` to make it read the password from its stdin.
Second, you should read or redirect the error stream somewhere to be aware of any errors.

Answer (score 2):

Old question but instead of trying to echo password you should setup your sudoers file to allow just that command with no password for that user

`myusername ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /path/to/my/program`

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18830/how-to-run-a-specific-program-as-root-without-a-password-prompt